# Use of PickleType in Flask-SQLAlchemy Doesn't Work

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pickle

I'm building a blog site with Flask. I'm trying to store all the tags for a post as a pickled Python list in SQLite3 database with Flask-SQLAlchemy. To use this, I must define a column as PickleType. I have set the default value of the column to [] to indicate no tags. However, when I create a entry in the command line, post.tags returns None instead of the default value []. Also, if I make changes to it, it doesn't update the entry after commit. I've attached the model definition class below for your reference. The best reference I've got is [this](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/). Kindly help me solve this issue.

```
class Post(db_handle.Model):
    id = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    timestamp = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.DateTime,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow
    )
    read_time_s = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.Integer,
        unique=False,
        nullable=True
    )
    title = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.String(150),
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    description = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.String(300),
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    content = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.Text,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    tags = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.PickleType, # XXX: Doesn't Work
        unique=False,
        nullable=False,
        default=[]
    )
    is_published = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.Boolean,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False,
        default=False
    )
    author_id = db_handle.Column(
        db_handle.Integer,
        db_handle.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        unique=False,
        nullable=True
    )
    comments = db_handle.relationship(
        "Comment",
        foreign_keys="Comment.post_id",
        lazy="dynamic",
        cascade="all,delete"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Post \"{self.title}\">"
```

I've recreated the steps after creating the database.

```
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jun  7 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.1.1 20230511 (Red Hat 13.1.1-2)] on linux
App: lib
Instance: /home/user/website/instance
>>> import lib
>>> from lib.blog.models import Post

>>> post = Post(
>>>    read_time_s=120,
>>>    title="Test Post",
>>>    content="Test Post",
>>>    description="Test Description" 
>>> )
>>> post.tags
>>> # Prints Nothing (None) | Expected []
```